# R package caret fails to load

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using R4.0.0, I used the 'caret' package successfully a week ago. But now when I am trying to rerun my program, I get the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
 cannot open file 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/iterators/R/iterators.rdb': No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This kind of error indicates that you need to reinstall the mentioned package — in tis case ‘iterators’, because its installation has missing or broken files. Maybe you updated your R version in the meantime, and this somehow broke stuff?

Comment: I tried reinstalling, but it does not help. I actually have not updated my R.

Comment: can you restart your R session, do `install.packages("iterators")`, then show us if there is any error when you call `library("iterators")`?

Comment: I did, I could call library(iterators), but now after I call caret I get the following error: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
 cannot open file 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/foreach/R/foreach.rdb': No such file or directory